# how to run service with WildFly server by wildfly-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, wildfly-10

I try to use wildfly-maven-plugin to build example service. 
The source code is:

https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/helloworld-html5

I want to simple use the wildfly-maven-plugin in maven pom.xml:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Alpha10</version>
        </plugin>
```

To build the test server like command:

```
 mvn wildfly:run
```

to run the server.

I can find the README.md
but the url written seems wrong.

I test the link:

http://localhost:8080/jboss-helloworld-html5/hello/json/YOUR_NAME

and

http://localhost:8080/hello/json/YOUR_NAME

All give me 404 error.

what is wrong of it?

how to make mvn wildfly:run can run this project?

Comment: the pom indicates the war name is going to be *wildfly-helloworld-html5*, not *jboss-helloworld-html5*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Gimby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424903/gimby) said your context path should be `wildfly-helloworld-html5`. It looks like the README is incorrect. The URL should be  http://localhost:8080/wildfly-helloworld-html5/hello/xml/YOUR_NAME and  http://localhost:8080/wildfly-helloworld-html5/hello/json/YOUR_NAME.

Also when you start you should see a log message on the console like the following.

```
08:22:18,281 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /wildfly-helloworld-html5
```

That will give you the context that was registered.